# Connecting Google Cloud Compute to Google Cloud SQL ERROR 2013 (HY000)

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

When trying to connect to mysql using the docker cloud proxy like so:

```
mysql -u <USERNAME> -p -S /cloudsql/<YOUR-PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>
```

I received this error

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 95
```

According to the documentation, this is how I'm suppose to setup the proxy

```
docker run -d -v /cloudsql:/cloudsql \
  -v /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt:/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt \
  b.gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy /cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql \
  -instances=<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>
```

Here is the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/compute-engine-access#gce-connect-proxydocker) for setting it up.

For those who may ask this question, I did set up these params properly

```
<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>
```

The output from the proxy:

```
2016/03/20 19:49:15 listenInstance: "<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>"
2016/03/20 19:49:15 Remove("/cloudsql/<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>") error: remove /cloudsql/<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>: no such file or directory
2016/03/20 19:49:15 Open socket for "<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>" at "/cloudsql/<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>"
2016/03/20 19:49:15 Socket prefix: /cloudsql
2016/03/20 19:51:29 Got a connection for "<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>"
2016/03/20 19:51:30 couldn't connect to "<PROJECT-ID>:<REGION-NAME>:<SQL-INSTANCE-NAME>": googleapi: Error 403: Insufficient Permission, insufficientPermissions
```

And so I looked at my compute instance and my Api access scopes for cloud sql is disabled and I had checked the [prerequisites](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/compute-engine-access#gce-connect-prereqs) before and they say that if I'm creating my cloud sql and compute instances in the same project then I my compute should have editor permissions.  Either way, I can't figure out how to give my compute instance editor privileges for my cloud sql instance.

Please let me know how I can give my compute instance editor privileges for cloud sql.

Comment: Can you include the output from the proxy?

Comment: Where do I get that?  There was no output when I used the docker run command.

Comment: Run `docker ps` to find the Container ID for the proxy, then run `docker logs <CONTAINER ID>` to see the logs.

Comment: Ok, I added the logs and I think it's a privileges issue.

Comment: What scopes did you create your GCE instance with? You can find this out by issuing `curl -H 'Metadata-Flavor: Google' "http://metadata/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/scopes?recursive=true&alt=text"` from your instance. You should see both `devstorage.read_write` and `sqlservice.admin` listed there; otherwise, you may need to recreate your instance with adequate scopes

Comment: Ok, that's interesting, I left it on `default access` in my instance template.  I wish default was `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` so I didn't have to go through this. Thanks for your help.  I'll let you know if this works, and then you can post the answer.

Comment: A couple things.  This [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/compute-engine-access#gce-connect-prereqs) is wrong and says the editor privileges are on by default if compute engine and cloud sql are in the same project, so this needs to be fixed. You're two options in your answer to fix this, aren't the problem I had.  I created instance templates, and I needed to set **Cloud API access scopes** to **Full API access to all Google Cloud services** option.  Please put that as a third option and I'll mark it as correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Went ahead and added the third options.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`insufficientPermissions` indicates that the Compute Engine VM is using the default Compute Engine service account and the Cloud SQL Admin scope was not enabled when the VM was created. In the first step of the guide, you are asked to verify whether the right scopes are present.

There are two options to fix this:

#### Option a) Create a new VM with the Cloud SQL Admin scope enabled.

When creating a new VM, select `Set access for each API` in the `Identity and API access` and switch `Cloud SQL` to `Enabled`.

[image]

If you are using **Instance Templates**, make the change described above on the instance template and use it to create the new instance(s).

Alternatively, you may select `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` but be aware that this will allow any application on the VM to access any of the Cloud APIs using the service account credentials, which has `editor` privileges on the project by default.

#### Option b) Use credentials for a different service account

If creating a new VM is not an option, you can [create a new service account](https://console.developers.google.com/permissions/serviceaccounts), download the credentials file to the VM and use the -credential_file parameter to make the proxy use it. The new service account must be granted at least `editor` access to the project.

There's an open issue to provide a better error message:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudsql-proxy/issues/6